# GSON don't serialize/deserialize extended class

Tags: java, gson

Is there an option (except writing custom serializer/deserializer) in `GSON library` to **NOT** serialize/deserialize beyond some level of extended classes.

For example see the following usecase

```
class FirstClass {
    int firstVariable;
}

class SecondClass extends FirstClass {
    int secondVariable;
}

class ThirdClass extends SecondClass {
    int thirdVariable;
}
```

And now when using `fromJson` and `toJson` I would like to only serialize/deserialize first two classes in hierarchy - `ThirdClass` and `SecondClass`. Which means it would ignore whole `FirstClass` (and `firstVariable` in it) because that's already at `level 3`.

Comment: Why is writing a custom type adapter problematic? You can compose type adapters which takes most of the maintenance pain away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot generically exclude the TopLevel Class, what you could do is use an `ExclusionStrategy`:

```
  private static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder().addSerializationExclusionStrategy(new ExclusionStrategy() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
        return f.getDeclaringClass().equals(FirstClass.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
        return false;
    }
  }).create();
```

You can also add a ExclusionStrategy to Deserialization.

Comment: So there is no other way than variable by variable?

Comment: You could always write your own custom TypeAdapters or Serializer/Deserializer, but i see no way of telling Gson to only de/serialize fields of classes lower in the hierarchy

Comment: I edited the answer slightly, now all fields in 'FirstClass' will be ignored. If you know the class you want to ignore I guess this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

The below example can help in skipping the certain variable with in the class during serialization

```
if (fieldAttributes.getDeclaringClass() == Example.class )
                && fieldAttributes.getName().equals("example")) {
            return true;
        }
```